# How to present data for repeated Title

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Sample file [Imdb sample](https://ufile.io/9kbarbs7)

In the film data set I have same titles available: 'A star is born' aka 'Narodziny gwiazdy' - four times, 'Halloween' - 3 times. These are different movies as released in different years.
How to filter only these titles which are present multiple times and display the details for them?

```r
(titleDetails <- imdb_movies.csv %>%
  group_by(Title) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  filter(count > 2))

titleDetails
```

Code above will display only title and count.

How to display all details which I have in the data set?

Comment: A small sample from your original data-frame would be helpful.

Comment: Updated. Sorry. My bad.

Comment: Please post data as text in the question, not a link. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `imdb_sample %>%
  group_by(Title) %>%
  filter(n() > 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `df[duplicated(df$Title) | duplicated(df$Title, fromLast = T), ]`.

`duplicated(df$Title)` returns a logical vector with `TRUE`s for all rows with a duplicated title. The *first* occurrence of the duplicated title will show as `FALSE`.

`duplicated(df$Title, fromLast = TRUE)` does the same thing, except in reverse order. This time, from the standpoint of the data you've supplied, the *last* occurrence of the duplicated title is marked `FALSE`.

Then, you can get *all* of the rows with duplicated titles by using the `|` (or) operator on these two `duplicated()` calls and index your original data using the resulting logical vector.